# Should I call Dispose() within a function after Return?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dispose, idisposable

Should I call .Dispose() after returning an object that implements IDisposable?

```
myDisposableObject Gimme() {
  //Code
  return disposableResult;
  disposableResult.Dispose();
}
```

In other words, is the object I return a copy, or is it the object itself? Thanks :)

Comment: Tip: It is not the method's responsibility to dispose of the returned object. It is the job of the caller. It *is* the responsibilty of the method to dispose on any resources that it created, if needed.

Comment: @AMissico: "It is not the method's responsibility to dispose of the returned object." Unfortunately, that's not true in general. For some methods and some property getters, the caller is responsible for disposing the returned object, for others it isn't, because the object is cached somewhere and disposed elsewhere. Apparently, there's no simple rule to find out which except trial&error.

Comment: Also, and someone correct me if I'm wrong, your last line never actually gets called anyway since the return exits the method.

Comment: @nikie: It is always true in managed code. I know of no exceptions to this rule in the .NET Framework libraries. (There are the exceptions that usually involve Interop to unmanaged code.) Obviously, you do not Dispose an object just because it implements `IDisposable`. There is no requirement that you call `Dispose`. The interface allows the programmer to "clean-up" unmanaged resources after an object is no longer needed. This a part of the design goals of the .NET Framework. To eliminate the need for the programmer to handle memory managment and memory-related bugs.

Comment: @nikie: "Apparently, there's no simple rule to find out which except trial-and-error;" I completely disagree. Read the documentation for the object in question.

Comment: @AMissico: There are lots of exceptions. For example, take `System.Windows.Forms.Control.GetChildAtPoint`. It returns an object that implements `IDisposable`, but in 99% of the cases, the caller wouldn't dispose that object, because the control still has a reference to it and will keep using it. This is an obvious exception, but there are less obvious cases. For example: you don't close the return value of `StreamWriter.BaseStream` every time you access. On the other hand, you do have to dispose the result of `Graphics.Clip` every time you invoke the property getter.

Comment: @nikie: I believe we are both talking about the same thing and in agreement. My tip is in regards to thinking about code responsibility when writing methods. As I stated, just because a method returns an object that implements IDisposable, the caller does not need to call Dispose. If the caller does, then they have to take responsbility of any exceptions or issues that arise.

Comment: @nikie: Since this is mananged code, I say that in "100% of the cases", the caller would not dispose that object because the Garbage Collector will take care of this for us. Unless the documentation states to call dispose. (See FileStream class remarks section.)

Comment: @nikie: "...you do have to dispose the result of Graphics.Clip every time you invoke the property getter." Why? The documenation makes no reference to calling Dispose. The property creates a new Region, calls GdipGetClip, then returns the Region. When the Graphics object is finalized and disposed, the Region will also be disposed. It is the responsbility of the Graphics class to dispose of the Region, because of the handles created by GdipGetClip. Your code has the option of calling Dispose to free system resources earlier, but it is not your code's responsibility.

Comment: @AMissico: It's dangerous to rely on the GC too much. Example 1: Imagine a managed object subscribes to an event. If you fail to Dispose it, it might live a lot longer than it should because the event holds a reference. Example 2: GDI+ ressources are limited. Not disposing them properly causes OutOfMemoryExceptions in the weirdest places (e.g. inside Button.Draw) which are very hard to track down.

Comment: @AMissico: I think you're wrong about `Graphics.Clip`. I've looked at the source and I'm quite sure the getter creates a new object *every time* I invoke it and never disposes the returned instance. It's the caller's duty to dispose it, just like `Graphics.Transform` (it's just not documented).

Comment: @nikie: Yes, you are right. Graphics.Clip does create a new Region every time. Yet, notice that it also creates a HandleRef for that Region. This allows the Graphics object to dipose of the object if, you, the Callee, choose not to dispose the Region. The Graphics object does this because it and a Region use unmanaged resources. (My reference is Microsoft's source code for .NET 2.0.) Therefore, in my opinioin, it is not "...the caller's duty to dispose it."

Comment: @nikie: "It's dangerous to rely on the GC too much." I disagree. The behavior you describe is what the GC is suppose to do. Microsoft provided the IDisposable interface to give us a tool in order to avoid problems with objects that have limited resources. As you mentioned, not "disposing them properly" is the key phrase and I find objects, especially derived objects, do not implement Dispose(bool disposing) properly.

Comment: @nikie: I feel we are in complete agreement. The difference between our opinions, is you feel calling IDisposable is "required". I do not agree. One design goal of .NET is to alleviate the need to "manage memory" and eliminate defects caused by "mismanaging memory".

Comment: @nikie: Should I call Dispose on the Matrix returned by Graphics.Transform? Note the documentation states, "you should dispose of the matrix when you no longer need it." (See Remarks section of Graphics.Transform property.) Notice it states "should". This is because, again, when the Graphics object is disposed, the Matrix will also be disposed because of the wrappers created by the Graphics object, as long as the callee is no longer using/referencing the objects. That is why documenation states, "should".

Comment: @nikie: I may add that in the above discussion, both Region and Matrix properly dispose of themselves in the Dispose(disposing) methods. Now a question to all you readers out there...what becomes of these objects, if you dispose of the Graphics object or the Graphics object gets disposed? You will experience the problems in the "weirdest places" as "nikie" mentions.

Comment: AMissico: My unmanaged ressources profiler (AQTime) said that the Region object created by Graphics.Clip has to be disposed by the caller. I asked the question on StackOverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361931/when-do-you-dispose-gdi-resources) and got the same answer. To me it seems entirely unclear which is correct - that's what inspired my ranting about the Disposable pattern.

Comment: @AMissico: BTW, could you explain why you think creating a temporary HandleRef instance would release the Region when the Graphics object is disposed? I can't see how that would work. HandleRef is a value type, so the local instance should be gone once it goes out of scope. It doesn't have a finalizer, either. And the only place I can find (using reflector) where `GdipDeleteRegion` is called is in the Region finalizer. So I don't see how it could be freed deterministically when the Graphics object is disposed.

Comment: @nikie: I do not agree with the only answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361931/when-do-you-dispose-gdi-resources because I think the conclusion "must dispose" is incorrect.

Comment: @nikie: "deterministically", you are changing the discussion and turning this into an argument. If you want to object to be freed "deterministically" then call IDisposable because that is what the interface is for. My point is you do not have to call IDisposable. It is the programmer's choice. (The GC and Finalizer will do this for you.)  My original point is you must consider a method's (code's) responsibility when creating objects and disposing objects.

Comment: @nikie: Lastly, HandleRef has nothing to do with allowing the Graphics object to dispose of the Region. I misspoke and confused HandleRef with a SafeHandle. Yet, as I stated earlier, "... both Region and Matrix properly dispose of themselves in the Dispose(disposing) methods."

Comment: @AMissico: I'm sorry, I didn't try to turn change the dicussion. I misunderstood you. I thought you claimed that the Region object *is* cleaned up deterministically. If you merely meant that it is eventually freed in the Finalizer, then of course you're right. But that's what causes the "weird problems" I mentioned, because the GDI+ objects may become Gen 2 or 3 and thus grow very old, leading to internal GDI+ problems (e.g. look at this blog post for a scary story about CT scanners: http://nomagichere.blogspot.com/2008/03/systemcomponentmodelwin32exception-is.html)

Comment: @nikie: I think if have GDI+ objects lasting until Gen 2 or Gen 3 then something else is going on.

Comment: @nikie: Regarding the CT Scanner blog entry. The documentation for ControlCreateGraphics clearly states, "The returned Graphics must be disposed through a call to its Dispose method when it is no longer needed." It is not optional to call the Dispose method. I have no sympathy for sloppy programming. I believe if they would have considered "code responsibility" the Graphics objects would have been cleaned up correctly, instead of letting "some other section of code worry about the object".

Comment: @nikie: I did some quick tests and profiling this morning and Regions get cleaned up nicely. You do have to watch those Graphics objects. As you mentioned, they will hang around. Even when they go out of scope. (It has to do with the required "sandwich" calls to GDI+ Startup/Shutdown the .NET Framework must perform.) That is why the documentation doesn't mince words and says "must be disposed".

Comment: @AMissico: You won't find subtle bugs like these with some quick tests and profiling. Regions can easily slip into Gen 2 or 3 if a GC collect occurs while some object draws itself. This happens rarely and indeterministically, so your code will work *most* of the time, and you will have a very hard time reproducing and narrowing down your bugs. That's just what the guy in the blog described. But it seems we are in agreement: not calling Dispose when you're supposed to call it and relying on the GC instead is "sloppy programming" and may lead to bugs.

Comment: @nikie: The blog entry is a really bad example. The code should never has been release. First, any personal or group code review would have found the problem before the code was checked in. Second, owner-drawn painting must be wrapped in a try...finally block (at the very least). Third, why this bug lastest months is beyond me. It should/could have been resolved on the very first review of the exception. Fourth, I doubt Microsoft was contacted. If they were, then they were given bad information or were never shown the source code.

Comment: @nikie: :O) I have been telling you we agree, since "May 14 at 16:55". "I believe we are both talking about the same thing and in agreement. My tip is in regards to thinking about code responsibility when writing methods." Sorry, couldn't resist :O)

Comment: @nikie: I have enjoyed our discussion. Happy Coding.

Comment: The owner of the object should dispose it.  This is a factory.  Factories create objects.  Unless the instance is a singleton and the factory owns it's life cycle, it should not dispose it.  And anyway, what good would a factory be if it disposed the object it was creating before it gave it to you? -- Also, putting any code after a return (without a try/finally block) is basically useless, the compiler should give you an unreachable code warning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the object itself. Don't call Dispose here, even if you reverse the order so that it gets called.

Answer (score 11):

No, you shouldn't. You return a reference to the object, so there is no copy made. In .NET, objects are never copied unless you specifically ask for it.

Also, you can't dispose the object with code like that even if there was a situation where you should. The code after the `return` statement will never be executed, and you will get a warning about unreachable code.

Answer (score 8):

One thing that none of the answers so far have mentioned is that you **should** dispose the object if `Gimme()` throws an exception.  For example:

```
MyDisposableObject Gimme() 
{
    MyDisposableObject disposableResult = null;
    try
    {
        disposableResult = ...

        // ... Code to prepare disposableResult

        return disposableResult;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        if (disposableResult != null) disposableResult.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Interesting, didn't know that. I'll start doing that with exception-prone objects.

Comment: This is a good suggestion in general for factories, etc. -- but with the code he posted, I'm not so sure -- and maybe it's just meant to be pseudo code -- but in the code he posted, it didn't *create* disposableResult -- it might be a shared object, etc.. -- the owner of an object should be the one to dispose it... if it created the object (or caused the object to be created) and was just going to set it up and hand it back, but instead threw an exception in the process, then yes, it should be the one to dispose it in this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

disposableResult.Dispose(); will never run, it is unreachable code as it will always return the line before.  Wrap the method call in a using staement and dispose of the object that way.
e.g.

```
using (DisposeableObject myDisposableObject = gimme())
{
    //code.
}
```

Comment: Your code will lead to compile error, because you used keyword `object` to name a variable :P

Comment: Yeah also i don't think the "...code." section is valid syntax either ;-)  I changed it anyway.

Comment: Usually, //... is what you use.

Answer (score 3):

The `.Dispose()` will never be reached anyway.

**Edit:** In my opinion, no, you shouldn't. You'd destroy the Object with that.

Answer (score 3):

If an object you are using implements `IDisposable`, you should construct and use in within a `using` statement - this will make sure it gets disposed of properly:

```
using(var mydisposableObject = new Gimme())
{
   // code
}
```

The way your code is constructed, you are returning the disposable object, so the call to `Dispose` will never be reached.

Comment: I meant this inside the function's body, not outside.

Comment: @Camilo Martin - No point in doing that as the call to `Dispose` will never be reached. You should wrap the call to this function with a `using` statement so `Dispose` gets called properly when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: If a "return mydisposableObject;" is executed within the "using" statement, a .Dispose of mydisposableObject will occur between the execution of the return statement and the caller's first chance to use mydisposableObject.  In most cases, this will render mydisposableObject completely useless to the caller.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it -- what's he's telling you is that your factory should not be disposing the object -- but the owner of the object (the thing that invokes your factory) should be disposing it.  (Unless your factory is handing back a singleton, of which it manages the life-cycle, but even then, it shouldn't dispose it right there -- it should dispose it elsewhere).

Answer (score 3):

If you  return the object, you should **not** dispose it before you return. It has to be up to the caller to dispose it.

Answer (score 1):

This line: `disposableResult.Dispose();` will not be executed. The returned "thing" is not a copy of object. It's a reference to object, so caller will manipulate on object created in `Gimme` and he (caller) should remember to dispose the object.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your code in a try/finally block

```
    try{
            int a = 0;
            return;
    }
    finally{
            //Code here will be called after you return
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree do not dispose this object it is being passed by reference.. There is a particular case I can think of when spawning objects where a class wraps another class and dispenses objects: You do not want the object dispensed to be a reference to the same one so you clone or pass a copy of the object and destroy the original, however if the original is a standard image for all spawns of that type, the object is not created specifically to each call and you anticipate numerouse spawns in a short period of time you may want to keep it as you can spawn a new object from that image without actually instantiating it again.. I would select to lock all properties on this to read only and cast the readonly object to a read/write object that can be used in the reallworld. The object should not be running any threads within itself when it is passed as value copy or clone, however if it is threading it is perfectly fine to pass it's reference  so long as the reference is a 1 to 1 relationship, if you have multiple pointers to an object who are concurrently reading and writing to that "running image" object you may begin to have collissions where a value has not been safely stored and the next pinger requests and assigns that same value. One thing we did not discuss when I was in school to a huge degree is object states. The object oriented principals were ingrained, but understanding why they were established has always taken time.. I'm backwords I learned object oriented style then moved in to more procedural styles.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question of mine is from 2.5 years ago so I can only comment on the writing style of your answer: please consider improving it a bit, as in its current state it looks a bit like a wall of text. It also has a few typos, and people here tend to be sensible to that. That said, thanks again for passing by and answering.

Comment: Sorry for the text wall, just wanted to state an instance where we would destroy an object.

Answer (score 0):

`myDisposableObject disposableResult = new myDisposableObject();`

Here `disposableResult` is a reference to the new object created. So when you return that reference to the calling method, that reference is still pointing to the created object in the heap. Hence you can safely dispose it in the calling method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have .Dispose() in the method which is returned.The caller should implement that.